# Gzip compression with MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, junit, compression, gzip, resttemplate

I have a Java application built on **Spring 3.2.0** performing an external call to a REST api serving JSON data.

The call is performed by the Spring **RestTemplate** class, with **Jackson** 2.2.3 as serializer/deserializer.

The call is functionnal and supports both plain and gzipped responses.

In order to Junit test the call, I use **MockRestServiceServer**. Everything works well, until I try to introduce gzip compression. I was unable to find in the offical doc how to activate gzip compression in MockRestServiceServer, so I went the manual route :

- manually gzip the String content of the response
- set the "Content-Encoding" to "gzip" in the headers

Unfortunately, I get the same error again and again, thrown by Jackson when deserializing the response body :

> ```
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): 
> only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
> at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@110d68a; line: 1, column: 2];
> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): 
> only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
> ```

Here is the current code (reworked due to corporate data...)

**Test class**

> ```
> public class ImportRefCliCSTest {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private MyService myService;
>
>     private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
>
>     @Before
>     public void before() {
>         mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(myService.getRestTemplate());
>     }
>
>     @Test
>     public void testExternalCall() throws IOException {
>
>         String jsonData = "[{\"testing\":\"Hurray!\"}]";
>         HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
>         headers.add( "Content-Encoding", "gzip" );
>
>         DefaultResponseCreator drc = withSuccess( gzip( jsonData ),
>             MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).headers( headers );
>
>         mockServer.expect( requestTo( myService.EXTERNAL_CALL_URL ) )
>             .andExpect( method( HttpMethod.GET ) ).andRespond(drc);
>
>         myService.performCall();
>     }
>
>
>     private static String gzip(String str) throws IOException {
>         if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
>             return str;
>         }
>         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
>         gzip.write(str.getBytes());
>         gzip.close();
>         String outStr = out.toString();
>         return outStr;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Service class**

> ```
> @Service
> public class MyService {
>
>     public static final String EXTERNAL_CALL_URL = "<myURL>";
>     private RestTemplate restTemplate;
>
>     {
>         restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
>             HttpClientBuilder.create().build()));
>     }
>
>
>     public void performCall() {
>
>         try {
>             HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
>             requestHeaders.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
>             HttpEntity<MyObject[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MyObject[]>(requestHeaders);
>
>             ResponseEntity<MyObject[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
>                 EXTERNAL_CALL_URL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, MyObject[].class);
>             MyObject[] array = responseEntity.getBody();
>             if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
>                 return null;
>             }
>             return null;
>         } catch (RestClientException e) {
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
>         return restTemplate;
>     }
> }
> ```

I feel I am missing something. The manual gzip compression seems rather suspicious.

Does anyone have an idea on this ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

When program convert gzip content to string, some bytes are collapsed. So client cannot decompress it and throw Exception. A solution is return `byte[]`:

```
private static byte[] gzip(String str) throws IOException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes());//consider to use str.getBytes("UTF-8")
    gzip.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi @beckyang. Thank you for your answer. I'll try this and come back to you